# How to get own peerID in a gamekit bluetooth connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit

I know how to get the other players peerID (from the didConnectPeer event or when i receive data) but how can i get the peerid of the iphone itself after a connection has been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're looking for is the [`peerId`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKSession/peerID) property on the [`GKSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) passed to you by the  [`peerPickerController:didConnectPeer:toSession:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate/peerPickerController:didConnectPeer:toSession:). delegate method.

Comment: Aah, youre right. I thought this was the other clients peerID but i guess its actually your own. 

"peerID - The identification string for the peer that connected to the session." //apple

Answer (score 0):

GKSession has a property called peerID. Although after testing, it looks as though this might not match your own peer ID.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found out too.

Comment: What a pain. This would be really useful, if only for filtering out one's own name from peer lists in GameKit.

Comment: I forgot that I actually solved it. Joachim Isaksson was right and I just missunderstood him at that time (thought he meant the parameter peerId rather than the peerID property on the session object. session.peerID is your own. I must say the documentation should make it more clear though. You sure you made your test correctly, works for me!